# evaluation of this contour integral which depend on a paramter $n$ ??

Tags: complex-analysis

evaluate the integral

$$ \oint_C dz \frac{\log\zeta(s)}{z^{n}} =a(n) $$

for $n=0,1,2,3,4$ the contour $C$ encloses all the poles and zeros of the Riemann zeta function

any hint to evaluate this ?? thanks

for the poles $z^n$ by residue theorem i should evaluate the $n$-th derivative of $\log\zeta(z)$ near zero but how about the other therm ??

Comment: Start by solving a simpler problem. Instead of the Riemann Zeta Function $\zeta(z)$, try $\zeta(z)=\frac{1}{z(z-1)}$ for example. Also be careful, $\log(\zeta(z))$ is NOT analytic at $z=0$.